# Array of pointers to every n-th element of bigger unsigned char array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, visual-c++

I have a huge array of unsigned chars (called *main_data*) containing some data, which is being refreshed once in a while. I would like to create an array (called *plot_data*) of pointers to every *n*-th element of *main_data*. **The idea is to upload new data to *main_data* from external source and to have reduced *plot_data* automatically available for my plot.** Here is my closest try (it is written in Managed C++, VC++ 2010, WinForms project):

```
    int mainDataSize = 64;
    int plotDataSize = 8;

    unsigned char* main_data = new unsigned char[mainDataSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < mainDataSize; i++) {
        main_data[i] = 2 * (i % 32);
    }

    unsigned char* plot_data = new unsigned char[plotDataSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < plotDataSize; i++) {
        int idx = (int)(mainDataSize / plotDataSize * i);
        plot_data[i] = main_data[idx];
    }

    printf("Original data:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < mainDataSize; i++) {
        printf("%d ", main_data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\nData for plot:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < plotDataSize; i++) {
        printf("%d ", plot_data[i]);
    }
```

**Then, after modification of *main_data*, I would expect that printing array of pointers would give me modified values.** Here is the code for modification and printing:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < mainDataSize; i++) {
        main_data[i] = i;
    }

    printf("\n\nChange made - Main data:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < mainDataSize; i++) {
        printf("%d ", main_data[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\nChange made - Plot data:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < plotDataSize; i++) {
        printf("%d ", plot_data[i]);
    }
```

I have been trying to fix this for few hours and it seems I don't get something, which should be relatively simple. Please, help me to understand my mistake.

Comment: `I would like to create an array (called plot_data) of pointers`  Where exactly did you do that?

Comment: `plot_data` is a copy of a piece of `main_data`. If you want to point *into* `main_data`, you only need `plot_data = main_data + starting_index`.

Comment: `unsigned char* plot_data = new unsigned char[plotDataSize];`  This is not an array of pointers.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to create an array (called plot_data) of pointers

The code you posted does not create an array of pointers.  It creates a dynamic array of `unsigned char`'s.

If you want to create an array of pointers:

```
unsigned char** plot_data = new unsigned char*[plotDataSize];
```

Then in the loop:

```
plot_data[i] = main_data + idx;
```

---

> Note this is bad code because there are memory leaks everywhere

I also recommend you use `std::vector`, as your code will leak memory if the proper calls to `delete[]` are not done.

```
#include <vector>
//...
std::vector<unsigned char> main_data(mainDataSize);
//...
std::vector<unsigned char*> plot_data(plotDataSize);
```

The leaks are now gone.

Comment: This was it, works like a charm now :) Thanks for memory leaks note, I forgot about that!

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an array of `chars`, not an array of `char *'s`.  You need to change your code to use an array of pointers:

```
int main()
{
    int mainDataSize = 64;
    int plotDataSize = 8;

    unsigned char ** main_data = new unsigned char * [mainDataSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < mainDataSize; i++) {
        main_data[i] = new unsigned char(2 * (i % 32));
    }

    unsigned char ** plot_data = new unsigned char * [plotDataSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < plotDataSize; i++) {
        int idx = (int)(mainDataSize / plotDataSize * i);
        plot_data[i] = main_data[idx];
    }

    printf("Original data:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < mainDataSize; i++) {
        printf("%d ", *main_data[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\nData for plot:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < plotDataSize; i++) {
        printf("%d ", *plot_data[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mainDataSize; i++) {
        *main_data[i] = i;
    }

    printf("\n\nChange made - Main data:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < mainDataSize; i++) {
        printf("%d ", *main_data[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\nChange made - Plot data:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < plotDataSize; i++) {
        printf("%d ", *plot_data[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mainDataSize; i++) {
        delete main_data[i];
    }

    delete[] main_data;
    delete[] plot_data;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for corrections, I messed this up a bit, now I think I get it